# Has "which were" been omitted before "noted" in this text?

Tags: seven-great-monarchies, george-rawlinson

Has "which were" been omitted before "noted" in this text from [*The Seven Great Monarchies Of The Ancient Eastern World, Vol 7*, last page of Chapter IX](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm#link2HCH0010)? See the quoted passage below, with emphasis added:

> naturally made all haste to reach his capital. Meanwhile the desire of keeping his army intact caused him to refrain from any movement which involved the slightest risk of bringing on a battle, and, in fact, reduced him to inaction. So much is readily intelligible. But what at this time withheld Sapor, when he had so grand an opportunity of making an impression upon Rome—what paralyzed his arm when it might have struck with such effect it is far from easy to understand, though perhaps not impossible to conjecture. The historian of the war ascribes his abstinence to a religious motive, telling us that the auguries were not favorable for the Persians crossing the Tigris. **But there is no other evidence that the Persians of this period were the slaves of any such superstition as that noted by Ammianus**, nor any probability that a monarch of Sapor’s force of character would have suffered his military policy to be affected by omens. We must therefore ascribe the conduct of the Persian king to some cause not recorded by the historian—same failure of health, or some peril from internal or external enemies which called him away from the scene of his recent exploits, just at the time when his continued presence there was most important. Once before in his lifetime, an invasion of his eastern provinces had required his immediate presence, and allowed his adversary to quit Mesopotamia and march against Magnentius. It is not improbable that a fresh attack of the same or some other barbarians now again happened opportunely for the Romans, calling Sapor away, and thus enabling Constantius to turn his hack upon the East, and set out for Europe in order to meet Julian.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of the clause "But there is no other evidence that the Persians of this period were the slaves of any such superstition as that noted by Ammianus" is correct.
The addition of "which were" before "noted" would be grammatically incorrect, since "any such superstition as that" assumes a single superstition, whereas "which were" is plural.

It is possible to find similar constructions elsewhere, for example (emphasis added):

- "This would appear to be the same structure **as that noted** by OS." ([Archaeology Notes](https://canmore.org.uk/event/733670), Canmore)
- "The Brexiteers’ alternative to the EU is just as imaginary **as that described by** Lear as a habitation for the Jumblies." ([*The Independent*, 23.11.2018](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/brexit-theresa-may-defeat-war-military-edward-lear-jumblies-a8648896.html))
- "The prayer related here by Luke is not precisely the same **as that mentioned by** Matthew; and indeed it is not likely that it was given at the same time." ([Commentary on Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/niv/luke/11-1.htm))
- "Director of the global research and analysis team at Kaspersky Lab, Costin Raiu, told Forbes the malware Mehta was investigating appeared to be the same **as that found by** BAE Systems, linking the Bangladesh bank heist group with Lazarus." ([Forbes, 15.05.2017](https://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2017/05/15/whos-behind-the-ransomware-pandemic-one-small-clue-points-to-north-korea/))

Comment: thank you very much